# Wordpress nextgen gallery plugin alternative

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking for alternative to the wordpress plugin nextgen gallery, i find lots of bug and funcionality lacks, so i'm looking for stable and flexible gallery plugin. Do you know one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found two that are quite decent:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/lightbox-gallery/
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/flash-album-gallery/